# Convergence of Gibbs Measures

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, field-theory

(I restrict my question to nearest-neighbor models for simplicity)

Let $\Lambda$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and $E$ be the set of nearest neighbor edges where both vertices lie within $\Lambda$.

A random field $\varphi:\Lambda\to S$ (where $S$ is some space, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ in the case of the Gaussian free field) is distributed according to the Gibbs measure $$ \frac{1}{Z_\Lambda}\exp\left(-\sum_{\{x,y\}\in E}J(\varphi_x,\varphi_y)\right)\mathrm{d}\varphi $$ where the interaction $J:S^2\to[0,\infty)$ is a symmetric function of sufficient regularity and $\mathrm{d}\varphi$ is a natural measure on $S^\Lambda$ (e.g. Lebesgue measure if $S=\mathbb{R}$).

For example, in the case of the Gaussian free field, $J(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)=\frac{\beta}{2}(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)^2$, $\beta$ being the inverse temperature.

Then infinite volume expectations, should they exist, are defined as $$ \langle F \rangle_{J} := \lim_{\Lambda\to\mathbb{Z}^d}\int_{\varphi\in S^\Lambda}F(\varphi)\frac{1}{Z_\Lambda}\exp\left(-\sum_{\{x,y\}\in E}J(\varphi_x,\varphi_y)\right)\mathrm{d}\varphi\,.$$

**My question**

What is the correct topology on the space of interactions $J:S^2\to[0,\infty)$ (symmetric functions which are regular in some sense, not sure what to require here..) such that convergence $J_n\to J$ in this topology would guarantee convergence of the *infinite volume* expectations $$\langle F\rangle_{J_n}\to \langle F\rangle_{J}\quad?$$

Comment: You could have a look at Theorem 4.17 and Proposition 4.19 in [Georgii's book](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110250329/html).

Comment: Indeed, Georgii's book suggested by Yvan would be the place look first, but I don't have it in front of me. It seems your question tries to avoid the existence problem for thermodynamic limits but is in fact intimately related to it. If $J$ is quadratic I would separate the square and only focus on the cross term $J \varphi_x\varphi_y$. Proving the thermodynamic limit can be done using monotonicity in the volume, i.e., Griffiths' 2nd inequality. Then if your $J_n$ increases towards $J$, you can commute the limits because you are commuting sups.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments. Indeed I was implicitly ignoring the existence of the infinite volume limit and understand that the two issues might be intimately connected. Actually we should not assume that $J$ is a quadratic polynomial. I would appreciate a concise sufficient condition on the type of convergence of $J_n\to J$ which would guarantee I suppose both existence of the infinite volume limit and the possibility to exchange the order of limits. I am looking into Georgii's book now, thanks.

Comment: If you are thinking of a $\phi^4$ model and the type of convergence is increasing convergence $J_n\rightarrow J$ then the argument I mentioned gives you convergence of infinite volume measures. If you put say $\phi^6$ then the argument does not work anymore because you get out of the Simon-Griffiths class and a priori loose monotonicity in the coefficients of the products $\varphi_x\varphi_y$. Georgii has a good survey at the end of various techniques for controlling the infinite volume limit for unbounded spins.

Comment: If I remember correctly Glimm-Jaffe in their book explain the Griffiths 2 inequality for lattice $\phi^4$ models. This gives that correlations increase with with the box $\Lambda$ and also the $J$.

Comment: I am not thinking of $\varphi^4$ but for example $J_n(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) = \frac{\beta}{2}(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)^2(1+\frac{1}{n}f(\alpha_1-\alpha_2))$ for some smooth but non-monotone $f$, say, $f=\sin^2$. Just a weird deformation of the Gaussian that converges to the Gaussian, but not monotonically.

Comment: Okay I see. I don't know if there are theorems available. Good news 1: this is a gradient type model and there is quite a bit literature for them see, e.g., the survey by Biskup https://projecteuclid.org/journals/probability-surveys/volume-8/issue-none/Recent-progress-on-the-Random-Conductance-Model/10.1214/11-PS190.full Good news 2: this is a small perturbation (by $\beta/n$) of a Gaussian and there are rigorous methods for that: cluster expansions and renormalization group. Bad news: your perturbed Gaussian is massless, so cluster expansions will not work.